# Movie, man does body swap. Young daughter knows he is not Daddy

Tags: story-identification, movie

Recently watched the movie *Self/less*, and it reminded me of another movie I had seen. (USA made, not sure how old, probably since 2000.)

In it a man has swapped bodies with someone. (I don't know the method, it could be like *Quantum Leap*, or alternate reality, or time travel, wish fulfilment. [I wish I had **his** life]) [I get strong vibes of a movie like *Mr. Destiny* (1990)]

The man is able to pass with all his friends and family as the original, with the exception of his young daughter (5-6 years old.)

The first time she sees him she runs to him saying "Daddy's home!!" (or something like that) and stops and says "You're not daddy."

Over the course of the movie, she keeps telling him you're not daddy, and more or less treats him as a friend or uncle instead of a father.  Like in *Self/less*, (when the girl tells Damian/Mark, "mommas b-day is March 22") she might be giving him hints/clues/reminders to help him fit in. (He is making her a bologna sandwich for her school lunch bag, she tells him, its supposed to be PB&J. Or he is putting something away on the middle shelf, and she tells him it goes on the top shelf. etc.)

At the end of the movie (the wish has been fulfilled, or reality and gone back to normal, or the body swap is over) and the little girl is sitting face to face with her father (or maybe he has picked her up) and she looks into his eyes and says something like "Daddy's back".

And the movie ends.

Comment: Do you remember the genre?

Comment: Since you mention it, that did happen in a Quantum Leap episode, except it was the mom. The older siblings assumed the little girl was just being weird, and the new "mom" quickly convinced the little girl he was helping her real mom, and it was temporary. The movie had to have been inspired by that episode.

Comment: @OwenReynolds Nice!, I saw a lot of QL (less than 1/2) when it first came out, but missed that one.

Comment: Amazing, I've been working my way through QL recently.  I just watched that episode of two days ago, then this question gets bumped.  Spooooky.    https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0681106/?ref_=ttep_ep13

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think that it may be "[The Family Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Family_Man)" starring Nicholas Cage.

*The film centers on a man who experiences what his life might have been if he had made a different decision earlier in his life.*
...
*On Christmas Day, Jack wakes up in a suburban New Jersey bedroom with Kate and two children.*

[image: The Family Man]

[image: Jack Campbell and his daughter]

Jack Campbell and his daughter

Comment: Heh. I was thinking Face/Off. This sounds pretty close.

Comment: Yes!! Thats it. I saw the scene on YouTube clip where the says he is not her dad, and it was as I remembered. I did not see the one where she says daddy's back. But everything else is as I remember. Thanks.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah Face Off would have been a good suggestion, but the daughter would have been too old to match the little girl.